# Use std::copy to copy two bytes from a char array into an unsigned short

Tags: c++

I have a binary array `char buffer[N];` which contains two bytes to be interpreted as an unsigned short at its beginning and am currently extracting those by doing

```
unsigned short size= 0;
memcpy((char *) &size, buffer, sizeof(unsigned short));
```

I would however like to use std::copy for this. Is this possible?

Attempts like

```
std::copy(buffer, buffer+sizeof(unsigned short), (char *) &size);
```

have resulted in various errors when compiling..

**Edit:** Sorry, I was in a hurry and forgot:
This is on a Ubuntu GNU/Linux system with gcc 4.4.3. The error message was `Error: Invalid conversion from ‘char*’ to ‘char’`.

Comment: What errors?  What compiler?  What operating system?

Comment: Try maybe `buffer+0` as the first argument. Add the actual errors to get meaningful answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not use any sort of bulk copy routine for this, nor should you use typecasting to get a pointer to `unsigned short`, because none of those options take byte order into account.  The correct way to extract a two-byte unsigned integer from a `char[]` buffer is with one of these functions:

```
unsigned short extract_littleend16(const unsigned char *buf)
{
    return (((unsigned short)buf[0]) << 0) |
           (((unsigned short)buf[1]) << 8);
}

unsigned short extract_bigend16(const unsigned char *buf)
{
    return (((unsigned short)buf[0]) << 8) |
           (((unsigned short)buf[1]) << 0);
}
```

`std::copy`, `memcpy`, and direct pointer bashing will all do the same thing as *one* of these functions, but *you don't know which one it'll be*, and any time you have this task, one of these functions is right and the other one is wrong.  Furthermore, if you don't know which one of these you need from context, go up a couple design levels and figure it out.

Comment: Indeed, this is the only real correct, portable and sane way to attempt such an operation.

Comment: But it completely ignores the OP's starting point (the `memcpy`).

Comment: Since we're being nit-picky maybe I should downvote you for using C-style casts instead of `static_cast`! If the OP doesn't care about byte order it is very possible that his target platform's byte order is maintained in the char array and he doesn't need to worry about it. Your answer is the portable way of doing this, but it is still no reason to downvote everyone else when their solutions work just as well for the OP. (I'm not actually downvoting since your solution works)

Comment: @Praetorian +10 perfect comment.

Comment: The OP may not have a byte-ordering problem *yet* but that is no excuse for doing this in a way that *will* break in the future, or worse, force someone else to go to extra trouble to cope with two unlabeled incompatible variations on a file format / network protocol.  Re style, it is my personal opinion that C-style casts are preferable to the more verbose but 100% equivalent `static_cast` for conversions among fundamental types, but in any case this is not remotely as big a deal as the byte-ordering issue.

Comment: In this case, there's no need for a cast at all; the values will be promoted to `int` whether or not you cast them to `unsigned short` first.

Comment: @Mike: although if `int` is 16 bits that's not what you want (since the `<<8` isn't guaranteed to have the right behavior w.r.t the top bit), and the whole point of this answer is to be picky about portability. On a hypothetical system where `short` and `int` are both 16 bits, `(unsigned short)buf[0]` will be promoted to `unsigned int` instead of `int`, and work, so the only reliance on sizes is the obvious (and unavoidable given the stated problem): that `char` is 8 bits and `short` is 16. `int` becomes irrelevant.

Comment: @SteveJessop: In that case they will be promoted to `unsigned int`, which is what you want, whether or not you cast them to `unsigned short` first. There are no circumstances in which the casts in this answer will have any effect on the result.

Comment: @Mike: that's not true. If `int` and `short` are both 16 bits, but `char` is 8 bits, then `buf[0]` (an lvalue of type `const unsigned char`) is promoted to `int`, whereas `(unsigned short)buf[0]` is promoted to `unsigned int`. It's a pretty complicated combination of implementation choices needed to break it, since we also need that `<<` is funny, but that combination conforms.

Comment: @Zack: so if I tell you that the only thing "wrong" with the data in buffer is that it might be mis-aligned, but that otherwise it is certainly an object representation of an `unsigned short` in host byte order, will you write code to check whether host order is big- or little-endian, so that you can call the correct one of your two functions? Or in that limited case would you row back from "you must explicitly choose byte order and call the corresponding function"?

Comment: @SteveJessop: Fair point, I was wrong about `unsigned char` promoting to `unsigned int`. You do need to either cast, or use unsigned values as the shift operands, to be fully portable to 16-bit, non-2's-complement platforms.

Comment: @SteveJessop @MikeSeymour Casting to unsigned is definitely necessary for this (because you really don't want a promotion to a signed type); given that, it would look odd to use `int` rather than `short` since the function returns a `short`.  I freely admit that my style preferences may be a little unusual.

Comment: @SteveJessop If you tell me that something has been serialized in "host" byte order, I want you to justify why it was necessary to serialize it in the first place.  I can think of a few cases where that really is appropriate, mostly having to do with machine code, but my first reaction is that the design is wrong.

Comment: @Zack Are you arguing that the design is wrong because it stores or transmits data in binary format?  (Perhaps I don't understand your last comment.)

Comment: @James: I think that what Zack is saying is: (1) Thou Shalt Not Define A Serialized Data Format To Be Host-Endian. Pick One; (2) if you have two bytes that represent a short but aren't already in a short, that's serialization, so see 1; (3) therefore this question doesn't need an answer, instead the surrounding code should be changed until the question goes away. We have to counter 1, by providing a detailed description of the program design that led to this (existing, working) code before Zack will engage with what calls to `copy` may or may not be equivalent to the `memcpy`.

Comment: Which I think is fair enough if you're in charge of code design for the project, and don't want host-endian serialized data formats to come back in future and bite you when they end up going over the network. It certainly prioritizes a teaching moment over answering the question that was asked, but the questioner accepted the answer and so presumably on this occasion there was indeed something wrong with the original design, and Zack caught it.

Comment: I wouldn't go as far as a "thou shalt not", just a "presumed to be a design error until proven otherwise". There are a few places where serialization in host byte order really is the Right Thing; the obvious example is relocation offsets in an object-code file format. (But you'll note that the ELF spec takes care to define "host byte order" relative to the architecture label in the header.  The native loader gets to avoid byteswapping, but the files are still unambiguous and processable on any CPU by code that's cautious.)

Comment: Also, fair cop on me jumping on a teaching moment over answering the immediate question.

Comment: @Zack: sorry, I did over-state your case and you had previously said there were some situations where host-endian is justified, which I ignored in re-phrasing you. I suppose the correct biblical / RFC 2119 wording is, "Thou Should Not Serialize Host-Endian" :-)

Answer (score 4):

you actually do not have to use any copy at all, that is the beauty of real pointers.
on a windows based system for example, you may use just this line of code.
try

```
size = *((unsigned short *)buffer);
```

<strike>std::copy needs iterators, and for that,</strike> i would stick to memcpy afterall

Comment: In all likelihood `std::copy` will be specialized for `unsigned short *` (and other pointers to primitive types) to call `memcpy` if it is faster for your platform. That is beauty of sticking to algorithms from the standard library.

Comment: Downvoted because of ignoring byte order. This answer is actively harmful, please delete it.

Comment: No, you're still ignoring byte order.

Comment: @Zack And you are still ignoring the question.

Comment: @Zack: Byte ordering is only an issue if the buffer is used to communicate with other computers. The question makes no mention of such a requirement. (Although this answer is wrong anyway, unless there is a guarantee that `buffer` has the correct alignment for `unsigned short`).

Comment: I do a lot of byte swapping, and from experience, unless you need to communicate to something that doesn't byte swap, then you need to leave it alone. It may be that the other side of the communication line byte swaps as well. So there's no need to consider unless you have context.

Comment: @MikeSeymour If the buffer isn't for communication with other computers (whether directly or via a persistent file) then it probably isn't necessary to serialize in the first place.

Comment: @Xaade Even if you know that all the computers *currently* participating in your protocol have the same preferred byte order, you should specify what that order is, and code as if the computers *didn't* have that order.  Slightly more work up front, but I find it pays for itself just in forcing you to think more carefully about what the bits on the wire will be, never mind the possibility that you might need to port to a computer with a different byte order in the future.

Answer (score 2):

```
size = *(unsigned short*)buffer;
```

should do ;-)

Comment: That should be `unsigned short *`, and it is unportable due to alignment issues.

Comment: Thanks, of course it should be `*`. Maybe, personally, last time I've seen the platform on which it wouldn't work over 20 years ago, but I'm sure there's a lot of modern platforms I haven't worked with.

Comment: @AndréCaron, how's that different from `memcpy` in terms of byte order?

Comment: Downvoted because of ignoring byte order.  This answer is actively harmful, please delete it.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker: it's not different, but that doesn't mean the byte order issue should be ignored.  It's very rarely possible to ignore it, and always a pain to debug when it becomes a problem.

Comment: @AndréCaron Then you should rather blame the OP for using incorrect code in the first place. But wait, maybe byte order is just unimportant/handled correctly in his case. You don't know. All you know is that he has a `memcpy` that behaves the same a Michael's answer.

Comment: @ChritianRau: that's why I posted a *comment*, and did not down vote this answer.  For posterity, anyone who reads this post will be reminded of the byte ordering issue.

Comment: Well, I don't know what is OP view of this data, I only know he wanted to copy two bytes.

Comment: Considerably more recent than 20 years ago, the ARM halfword load instruction requires 2-alignment, so it won't work on modern ARM devices if the compiler uses that instruction for `short`.

Answer (score 2):

Ok my answer a bit clarified:

You can do it this way and it **should **compile**** without problems, see the code below. However, you don't really want to do it this way because it has a few caveats.

1.: It will screw badly if the native byte order is different from the byte order in the char buffer (see 4, Credits due to Zack - I missed that point myself).

2.: If you mess up the cast you will end up in the middle of undefined behavior (see comments on the post, I first missed to specify the cast)

3.: Debug implementations of the STL might warn or at all prevent you from compiling code like this (and they do so for a reason).

4.: It might compile and seem to be working well but it doesn't necessarily do what you intended it to do (see 2.)

5.: I'm sure there more :)

Here is the **compiling** example (i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2). Use at your own risk.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  unsigned short foo = 0;
  char byte[2] = { 0x10, 0xFF };

  // WARNING: This will screw up if the native byte order is different 
  // from the byte order in the buffer!!! (Credits: Zack)**
  std::copy(byte, byte + sizeof(unsigned short), (char*)&foo);

  std::cerr << foo << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That interprets `&foo` as a 2-element array of `short`s and will stomp on other parts of the spec. Don't do this!

Comment: You sure that works perfectly well?  I would expect it to copy 0x10 into `foo` and write 0xff on the stack somewhere.  Each increment will be `sizeof(short)` because of the type of `foo`.

Comment: ok - my error, have been to quick hacking something in without thinking. added cast, compiles and works fine, just as the OP intended it to work.

Comment: I'm not downvoting this because it does demonstrate that `std::copy` can be used for this if you don't care about byte order, and that's the question that was asked; however, please add some sort of warning about how this will screw up if the native byte order is different from the byte order in the buffer.